# Unreachable statement?

Tags: java, methods, return

Here is my coding:
For some reason, at the very end, when I'm trying to return winscounter and losscounter, it says unreachable statement but not for the tiescounter. I can't figure out why! If anyone can answer this, it would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static int value;  //computer's choice
    static int choice; //user choice
    static int tiescounter = 0;
    static int winscounter = 0;
    static int losscounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));// user input

        int repeat;

        do {
            System.out.println("ROCK PAPER SCISSORS"+
                    "\n===================");
            System.out.println("\n1=Rock" +
                    "\n2=Paper" +
                    "\n3=Scissors" +
                    "\n===========" +
                    "\nChoose:");

            choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            if (choice !=1 && choice !=2 && choice !=3) {

                do{
                    System.out.println("\nError. Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors.");
                    choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                }
                while (choice !=1 && choice !=2 && choice !=3);
            }

            System.out.println();

            if (choice == 1){
                System.out.println("You have chosen Rock.");
            }
            else if (choice ==2){
                System.out.println("You have chosen Paper.");
            }
            else if(choice == 3){
                System.out.println("You have chosen Scissors.");
            }

            randomWholeNumber();

            if (value == 1){
                System.out.println("The computer has chosen Rock." );
            }
            else if (value == 2){
                System.out.println("The computer has chosen Paper." );
            }
            else if (value == 3){
                System.out.println("The computer has chosen Scissors." );
            }

            determineOutcome();
            System.out.println("Ties:"+ tiescounter);
            System.out.println("Wins: " + winscounter);
            System.out.println("Losses: " + losscounter);

            repeat = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        }
        while (repeat==1);
    }

    public static int randomWholeNumber(){

        do{
            value=0;//resets random number
            //generates and returns a random number within user's range 
            value = (int) ((Math.random()*3)+1);
        } 
        while((value>3)||(value<1));
        return (value);
    }

    public static int determineOutcome(){

            if (value == choice){
                System.out.println("\nYOU'VE TIED");

                do{
                    tiescounter+=1;
                }
                while (tiescounter != tiescounter);
            }

            else if (value == 1){ //Rock
                if (choice == 2){ //Paper
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE WON");               
                    do{
                        winscounter +=1;
                    }
                    while (winscounter != winscounter);
                }
                else if (choice == 3){ //Scissors
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE LOST");
                    do{
                        losscounter+=1;
                    }
                    while(losscounter!=losscounter);
                }
            }

            else if (value == 2){ //Paper
                if (choice == 1){ //Rock
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE LOST");
                    do{
                        losscounter+=1;
                    }
                    while(losscounter!=losscounter);
                }
                else if (choice == 3){ //Scissors
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE WON");

                    do{
                        winscounter +=1;
                    }
                    while (winscounter != winscounter);
                }
            }

            else if (value == 3){ //Scissors
                if (choice == 1){ //Rock
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE WON");
                    do{
                        winscounter +=1;
                    }
                    while (winscounter != winscounter);                    
                }
                else if (choice == 2){ //Paper
                    System.out.println("\nYOU'VE LOST");
                    do{
                        losscounter+=1;
                    }
                    while(losscounter!=losscounter);
                }
            }

            return(tiescounter);
            return(winscounter);
            return(losscounter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only return one int.  When `tiescounter`  is returned,  the function ends.  `return(winscounter);` and `return(losscounter);` is never executed,  that causes your error.

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return one value.  As soon as `return(tiescounter);` is executed the function exits.  If you want to return all three values you will have to wrap them in a class.

By the way `return(tiescounter);` can be written as `return tiescounter;`  Parenthesis around return values is not required.  Both statements will have the same result.

Comment: `return(tiescounter);` is a perfectly valid statement. There's no reason to remove the parentheses.

Comment: Yea your probably right, it's personal style.  It is however, not required

Comment: a function can have multiple return statements but only in different control flow

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return 3 different variables from one method, all at the same time. In this case, the `return(tiescounter);` always executes, terminating the method then and there. Hence the next 2 lines become unreachable.

Declare  `determineOutcome()` method as void i.e. `public static void determineOutcome()`, and remove all return statements inside it. Your program will work.

Comment: @Annie Yu: Exactly. You ca return only one thing at a time from a function(method). If you want to return more than one thing, then probably use some data structure(say array).