# How is this an "unreachable statement"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unreachable-statement

I am making a login page, and i would like it if "Successfull login" appears in the console if the username and password match the database. So i simply added a `System.out.println();` in the if statement, but it gets the error "unreachable statement". Why is that? Here is the loop:

```
if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(userFromDB) && hashedPass.equals(passFromDB)) {
        return "Correct username and password!";
        System.out.println("Login successfull using username \"" + user + "\"");
    }
```

Comment: A return statement is the last reached line of your method, as it stops the method execution. Everything you put after it is unreachable.

Comment: The return keyword is used to return from a method when its execution is complete. When a return statement is reached in a method, the program returns to the code that invoked it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreachable statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139376/unreachable-statement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a loop, it is a conditional statement and even if it would be a loop it woudln't change a thing.

This is an unreachable statement because return is the place where you get out of the method and return a value of an expression that is next to the `return` key word.

Comment: Yep. I realised that myself.

Comment: @YCF_L i will, but you need to wait 15 minutes.

Comment: @YCF_L: The OP doesn't *have* to accept an answer. It's a good idea to do so, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: What the honor, @JonSkeet is here, You are correct JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

Put your System.out.println() before the return statement. 
The return statement take the compiler out of the function and the println() statement won't be executed at all.